# Quote all text in GMail reply, not just selected text

Tags: gmail

How can I quote all text in a GMail reply, not just selected text?

Comment: Just don't select any text when replying. Or are you asking something else? It's not clear from your question. Can you add some more details?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have GMail quote all text even when I have text selected - otherwise I have to remember to unselect it. Other mail clients provide this option, and I could have sworn I found how to enable it in Gmail a while ago.

Comment: Ah. The answer then is "you can't". Either unselect the text or select all the text.

Comment: You might be remembering the feature when it was [still in labs](http://www.sgi.nu/diary/2008/09/12/quote-selected-text-a-useful-gmail-labs-addition/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Just to provide some background:** Right now, it doesn't seem like you can turn this feature off.

There used to be a labs feature [to turn "quote selected text" on](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/09/new-in-labs-reply-add-ons.html). Very recently (mid-November '12) they turned it on by default, without providing a way to disable. I haven't been able to find any official mention of it, only comments from others who have noticed the change and miss the old way.

Comment: I sympathise :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't (thanks Al Everett in comments above.)